# django get_or_create method always results in a new record

Tags: python, django

Model

```
class projects(models.Model):
"""Table that holds the details of the projects."""


    toiName =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toiOwner =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toiOwnerEmail =  models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    receiverEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    managerEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    dateUpdated= models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today())
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today())

    class Meta:
        db_table="projects"
```

View, the original code to save the model works fine, when I go ahead and edit the form in the view, I always end up with a new record.

```
    data = model_to_dict(projects.objects.filter(toiName=pid, managerEmail=request.user)[0])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = projectsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #form = projectsForm(request.POST, instance=projects.objects.get(toiName=pid))
            #obj = projects\
            obj, created = projects.objects.get_or_create\
                                (toiName=request.POST['toiName'],
                                toiOwnerEmail=request.POST['toiOwnerEmail'],
                                toiOwner=request.POST['toiOwner'],
                                manager=request.POST['manager'],
                                receiver=request.POST['receiver'],
                                receiverEmail=request.POST['receiverEmail'],
                                dateUpdated=datetime.now(),
                                dateCreated=data['dateCreated'],
                                managerEmail=request.user,)
```

Here created always results in True.

Comment: There are to many arguments in get_or_create . if one of has `trailing space` , it will result in new record . try triming POST data .

Answer (score 3):

At least this `dateUpdated=datetime.now()` causes `get_or_create` to always create new record, because each time `datetime.now()` is different.

Comment: I changed that from auto_now_add based on a blog entry http://alexkehayias.tumblr.com/post/33889961953/django-gotcha-duplicate-models-when-using

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was using the get_or_create incorrectly, since I was only trying to update the entry.

I fixed the code in the view with:

```
    data = model_to_dict(projects.objects.filter(toiName=pid, managerEmail=request.user)[0])
proj =  projects.objects.get(toiName=pid, managerEmail=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = projectsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        proj.toiName=form.cleaned_data['toiName']
        proj.toiOwnerEmail=form.cleaned_data['toiOwnerEmail']
        proj.toiOwner=form.cleaned_data['toiOwner']
        proj.manager=form.cleaned_data['manager']
        proj.receiver=form.cleaned_data['receiver']
        proj.receiverEmail=form.cleaned_data['receiverEmail']
        proj.dateUpdated=datetime.now()
        #proj.dateCreated=data['dateCreated']
        proj.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

additional to @user1865366 answer, `projects.objects.get` should be enclose it with `try ... except ...`  like so

```
try:
    proj = Projects.objects.get(toiName=pid,manageEmail=request.user)
except Projects.DoesNotExist :
    # do something create new proj and do something with the form
    ...
```

otherwise there will be big error screen when django cannot get the object